# Acrobat Pro DC ComboBox - Current selection doesn't match its index

Tags: javascript, combobox, adobe, acrobat

Using a Validate function to process a ComboBox selection, I can get the value of the current selected item but the index of the item is always the previous selection's index:

```
var combo   = this.getField("combo");
var options = [
    [   "Option a"  ,   4   ],
    [   "Option b"  ,   8   ],
    [   "Option c"  ,   15  ],
    [   "Option d"  ,   16  ],
    [   "Option e"  ,   23  ],
    [   "Option f"  ,   42  ]
]

combo.setItems( options )

combo.setAction("Validate", "someFunc(event)")

function someFunc(e){
    console.println(e.value)                    // Option c
    console.println(combo.currentValueIndices)  // 0
}
```

I'm expecting the result to be:

```
// option c
// 2
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Pull your code out of the function and put it into a custom KeyStroke script then use e.changeEx instead of e.value.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Joel, I'm sure that would work, but I'd like to have all my code in one file without using the properties window if possible.

Answer (score 0):

In that case, use something link this...

```
combo.setAction("Keystroke", "console.println(event.changeEx);console.println(this.getField('combo').currentValueIndices"))
```

Comment: `currentValueIndices` is still showing the index of the previously selected item in the combobox

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I changed:

```
combo.setAction("Validate", "someFunc(event)")
```

to:

```
combo.setAction("Format", "someFunc(event)")
```

And I now get the correct `currentValueIndices`.

Comment: That's because the format script is the last to run, it occurs after the field value has been updated. During the validate event, the value hasn't changed yet. It only changes if the validation is good (true). In the keystroke event, the changeEx property is the new value. The currentValueIndicies haven't changed yet either.